# Javascript if statment works not correctly

Tags: javascript, html

i have one question how can i change the strong value wheen the h2 value != autos

check my code

HTML 
Want to change the Merk to type if #merk is not autos

```
<h2><strong>Categorie: </strong><span id="merk">Bijoux-Horloges</span></h2>
 <h2><strong id="type">Merk: </strong>Bijoux</h2>

var categorie = document.getElementById("#merk");
var type = document.getElementById("#type");

if(categorie != 'autos'){
    document.getElementById("#type").innerHTML = "Type";
}
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: remove the `#` from your selectors, they are invalid

Comment: To elaborate on @SterlingArcher's point: you only want the `#` if you're using `querySelector()` (or jQuery's `$()` function), not `getElementById()`).

Comment: Also, you're already caching the element in a variable `type`, no need to call it again. Just use `type.innerHTML = "Type";` (preferably use textContent as @Dai said)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `textContent` (thanks to [@Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai)):

```
if(categorie.textContent != 'autos'){
    document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = "Type";
}
```

Furthermore, you don't want any other characters in your `getElementById`, those would be used for `querySelector`, [css](/questions/tagged/css) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

Comment: `textContent` is preferable to `innerHTML` when dealing with text.

Comment: This is not the issue either way, the octothorp in `getElementById` is invalid

Comment: @SterlingArcher It *is* one issue because they were trying to compare an HTMLElement to a string which would never be true.

Comment: its worked  i just used the answer of @Dai thank you all guys. have a nice day all

Comment: @AndrewLi ah I missed that part, was focused on the `#` and thought it was the assignment. Good point

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h2><strong>Categorie: </strong><span id="merk">Bijoux-Horloges</span></h2>
 <span id="test"></span>


<script>
var categorie = document.getElementById("merk").textContent;
var test = document.getElementById("test");

if(categorie != 'autos'){ 
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>Merk: Bijoux</h2>";
}else{
 test.innerHTML = "<strong>Merk: </strong>Bijoux";
}

</script>
```

Well i'm not sure what you meant by

> HTML Want to change the Merk to type if #merk is not autos

but this changes the strong tag to h2 when the value != autos

Comment: thank you for your answer but it was already solved and i neded that wheen is not category 'autos' to change the h2 Merk to Type. but it is already done, still thank you bro ;)